# Using chart.js2 for React, how can I add text at a specific place on the chart?

Tags: reactjs, chart.js2

I am using chart.js 2 in React. I have this horizontal line, on top of which on the graph itself I would like to place a label, right above the dotted-line.

I have seen a lot of this on chart.js in pure vanilla JavaScript, but it's a little bit different in a react application it seems. Thank you

[image]